# Getting Icecast output module settings within Liquidosap on_metadata handler

Tags: ocaml, liquidsoap

I have built a streaming server that is compatible with Icecast sources, but can accept additional metadata.  A typical Icecast source client will send its out-of-band metadata update request to the server like this:

```
/admin/metadata?pass=hackme&mode=updinfo&song=Artist%20-%20Title
```

My server accepts additional querystring parameters, like `meta[album]` and `meta[filename]`:

```
/admin/metadata?pass=hackme&mode=updinfo&song=Artist%20-%20Title&meta[album]=Album%02Name&meta[filename]=somefile.mp3
```

I am trying to configure Liquidsoap to send this extended metadata.  According to the documentation, it seems I can [disable the built-in metadata](http://savonet.sourceforge.net/doc-svn/icy_metadata.html) updates by setting `icy_metadata=false`.  From there, I should be able to [write my own function to handle `on_metadata`](http://liquidsoap.fm/doc-svn/reference.html#on_metadata).  The documentation gives the following signature for `on_metadata` calls:

```
(?id:string,(([(string*string)])->unit),source('a))->
source('a)
```

> Call a given handler on metadata packets.
>
> - id (string – defaults to ""): Force the value of the source ID.
> - (unlabeled) (([(string*string)])->unit): Function called on every metadata packet in the stream. It should be fast because it is ran in the main thread.
> - (unlabeled) (source('a))

I don't fully understand this signature, but I found a [mailing list post that has a good example](https://www.mail-archive.com/savonet-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07274.html):

```
def send_meta(m) =
  system("/path/to/script #{m["title"]} #{m["artist"]}")
end

source = on_metadata(send_meta, source)
```

With this information, I should be able to call out to cURL to make a request to my server, updating the metadata.  Something like this:

```
system("curl \"http://HOST:PORT/admin/metadata?pass=PASSWORD&mode=updinfo&song=#{m["artist"]}%20-%20#{m["title"]}&filename=#{m["filename"]}\"")
```

I'm close, but I can't figure out the last parts of this:

- How can I get the configured host, port, and password for the associated Icecast Output?
- How can I appropriately URL-encode the metadata parameters?
- Is there some sort of debugging output I can use to show all available variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all turned out to be very simple.

> How can I get the configured host, port, and password for the associated Icecast Output?

It isn't possible, directly.  The metadata handler doesn't get a reference to the source.  However, it's trivial to write a function that sets up both at the same time.

```
def output.my_custom_output(encoder, source, host, port, password, mount, genre, url, name) =
  def send_meta(m) = 
    # Code to send metadata here.
    # You can use source, host, port, etc
  end

  output.icecast(...)
end
```

> How can I appropriately URL-encode the metadata parameters?

```
url.encode(m['filename'])
```

> Is there some sort of debugging output I can use to show all available variables?

There may be a better way, but I've found that JSON-encoding and outputting to the log to be helpful.

```
log(json_of(m))
```